# Redirecting WordPress page to HTTPS - not redirecting

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect, https

Pages on our WordPress site are not automatically redirecting to the HTTPS version even though we have set the site url and home url to use HTTPS.

This is the code we have at the top of our wp-config.php file:

```
define('WP_HOME','https://webwisemedia.co.uk');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://webwisemedia.co.uk'); 
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

Our .htaccess file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

If you visit a page on our site, like http://webwisemedia.co.uk/web-wise-in-the-press/, it doesn't redirect to the HTTPS version.

Any ideas why?

Comment: You should not add anything between the `# BEGIN WordPress`/`# END WordPress` comments - that is the part of the .htaccess that WP will _overwrite_ when you change any settings that affect rewriting or URL structures. You need to place your own stuff outside of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed up the Wordpress part of .htaccess and that is why it isn't working. That part is changed every time you update, for example, permalinks. Your .htaccess should look like this:

```
# Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This leaves the Wordpress part intact and it forces to use https. From now on if you change anything in .htaccess do it below the Wordpress part.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have updated the .htaccess file to the above but when I go to http://webwisemedia.co.uk/how-to-make-the-most-of-wordpress/ it still doesn't redirect to https?

Comment: @NicholasLeonida I have updated the code. I made a small mistake which couldn't force your page to go to https :) Try entering this whole code into your htaccess file